# Insert multiple files (images, videos,word etc) to database

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a winform application for archiving files into database.
For selecting the files i used the code below :

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = true;
        dlg.Filter ="Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|" +
   "All files (*.*)|*.*";

        DialogResult dlgRes = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlgRes == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            foreach (String file in dlg.FileNames)
            {
                // Create a PictureBox.
                try
                {
                    Label name= new Label();
                    Label fullpath = new Label ();
                    Label ext= new Label();

                    name.Text = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    fullpath.Text = file;
                    ext.Text = Path.GetExtension(name.Text);

                    flpName.Controls.Add(name);
                    flpFullPath.Controls.Add(fullpath);
                    flpExt.Controls.Add(ext);

                }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
```

And for inserting to database i used this code:

```
foreach (Control f in flpFullPath.Controls)
        {


                //try
                //{
                //Read File Bytes into a byte array
                byte[] FileData = ReadFile(f.Text);
                string path = Path.GetFileName(f.Text);
                //Set insert query
                string qry = @"Insert into FilesStore (Linja, Magazina, Arkiva, OriginalPath,FileData,Lloji, Data,NrProt, EmriDok,Perdoruesi) values(@linja,@magazina,@arkiva,@OriginalPath, @FileData, @lloji, @Data,@nrprot, @emr,@perdoru)";

                //Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
                SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;              // Use current time
                string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";    // modify the format depending upon input required in the column in database 
                                                          // string insert = @" insert into Table(DateTime Column) values ('" + dt.ToString(format) + "')";
                                                          //We are passing Original File Path and File byte data as sql parameters.

                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@linja", (object)cbLinja.Text));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@magazina", (object)cbDokMagazina.Text));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@arkiva", (object)cbArkiv.Text));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalPath", (object)f.Text));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileData", (object)FileData));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lloji", (object)cbLloji.Text));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data", (object)dt.ToString(format)));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nrprot", (object)txtDocProt.Text));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emr", (object)Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)));
                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@perdoru", (object)lblPerd.Text));

                //Open connection and execute insert query.
                con.Open();

                SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

            }
```

My problem is with the inserting code. When i select 5 different pictures, the code uploads only 1 picture 5 times into database.

Comment: Are all of the fields inserted into the database duplicates, or is it just the FileData that is duplicated?

Comment: the fields also. the thing is that i want that the fields to be duplicated but the FileData no. there are multiple pictures and documents that are part of the same category

Comment: Does setting a breakpoint in either foreach indicate that you are enumerating different files?

Comment: when i set a breakpoint the all 5 pictures are insertet sucessfuly .when i remove the breakpoint and run the app it shows the problem again.

Comment: You do something weird. You mix GUI with your logic. DO NOT do that. You should create list of filenames chosen by user and then pass this list to inserting code. And what you do now is create some labels and then iterate throught ALL controls in flpFullPath.Controls hoping that every control has different file name. Do it properly.

Comment: You use the same control values (`cbLinja.Text` etc) as parameter values on each iteration.

Comment: I think it needs a for loop or something